# "Opposite" Lipschitz constant (?)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, lipschitz-functions

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is $L$-Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L$ iff $|f(x + \Delta) - f(x)| \leq L|\Delta|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

Analogously is there a name for the almost-opposite concept $|f(x + \Delta) - f(x)| \geq K|\Delta|$ ?

Comment: I don't know a name, but such a function $f$ will necessarily be a homeomorphism and the inverse $f^{-1}$ will be $1/K$-Lipschitz.